# What should be the SMTP server when using the Amazon MAIL FROM domain?

Tags: domain-name-system, smtp, amazon-ses

I have set up a MAIL FROM domain with Amazon SES by following their instructions: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/mail-from.html

They have verified that the DNS records were set correctly.

However when I send an email using SMTP and the server being: email-smtp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com I get the following error on mail-tester.com: HEADER_FROM_DIFFERENT_DOMAINS    From and EnvelopeFrom 2nd level mail domains are different

So I tried sending it using the subdomain (MAIL FROM domain) for which I created an MX record and a TXT record, but the email software (Sendblaster) says that the server cannot be found. Do I need to also set up an A record for this to work? Or is the solution elsewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that you need to set the MAIL FROM domain for each verified email and not just for the domain.

This solved it.